# To find favor in one’s eye?

Tags: commentaries, language

What does the idiom: מצא חן בעיני (to find favor/grace in one’s eyes) express, what does it really mean and when is it used in the Tenach?

I noticed it’s almost always connected to a request of some kind.

In modern days it seems to mean something like finding ‘likeability’ in the eyes of someone; i.e. ‘if you like’. So is this expression used to gain someone’s approval or support?

Hopefully someone could help me difine the meaning of this phrase.

Comment: What make you suspect מצא חן בעיני might not mean something like finding ‘likeability’ in the eyes of someone? In other words: Why not understand it in the way it seems to mean in modern days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [several places](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%90%20%D7%97%D7%9F%20%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99&tab=text&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance) where this idiom (מצא חן בעיני) can be found. One of these places is in Bereishis 6:8, where it says that Noach found favor in G-ds eyes:

> But Noaĥ found favour in the eyes of the L-rd.

[The Radak](https://www.sefaria.org/Radak_on_Genesis.6.8.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) on this pasuk explains that מצא חן בעיני means that his deeds were pleasing to G-d.

> 'ונח מצא חן בעיני ה, he found favour due to good deeds performed by him. The Torah uses the same expression in Exodus 33,17 when G’d tells Moses that he had found favour in His eyes. His deeds had been pleasing to G’d. In Bereshit Rabbah 28,9, Rabbi Acha son of Kahana expresses surprise at the words ונח מצא חן בעיני ה', saying that the wording implies that Noach, in his own right, could not have claimed the right of survival, except for the circumstance that he “found favour in the eyes of the Lord, i.e. G’d had to search for a reason to let him survive. [He bases himself on the whole verse being superfluous, as Noach’s merits are discussed in the following verses. Rabbi Einhorn’s comment on that Midrash. Ed.]

A similair idea can be found in the commentary by the [Ramban](https://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Genesis.6.8.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> BUT NOAH FOUND GRACE IN THE EYES OF THE ETERNAL. The meaning thereof is that all his deeds were pleasing and sweet before Him. Similarly: For thou hast found grace in My sight, and I know thee by name.518 This is like the verses: And He gave him favor in the sight of the keeper of the prison;519 And Esther obtained favor in the sight of all of them that looked upon her.520 Scripture mentions this in contrast to what it said concerning his [Noah’s] generation, namely, that all their deeds brought grief before Him, blessed be He. But of Noah it says that he found grace in His eyes, and afterwards it tells521 why he was pleasing before G-d: because he was a perfectly righteous man.
> Noach

See also the commentary of the [Toledot Yitzchak on Bereishis 6:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Toledot_Yitzchak_on_Torah%2C_Genesis.6.8.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

[The Yerushalmi (Shekalim 3:2)](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Shekalim.3.2.1?vhe=The_Jerusalem_Talmud,_edition_by_Heinrich_W._Guggenheimer._Berlin,_De_Gruyter,_1999-2015&lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) cites [Proverbs 3:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.3.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) "so shalt thou find grace and good understanding in the sight of G-d and man".

The [Ikar Tosafot Yom Tov on Pirkei Avot 3:10:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Ikar_Tosafot_Yom_Tov_on_Pirkei_Avot.3.10.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) explains:

> "Anyone from whom the spirit of creations find pleasure": As it is stated (Proverbs 3:4), "And find grace and good intellect in the eyes, etc." and it says, "And the kindness of the L-rd is for ever and ever on those that fear Him" - such that anyone who He places upon him His 'string of kindness, it is certain that he is one who fears Heaven.

Please also note what the [Orchos Tzadikim](https://www.sefaria.org/Orchot_Tzadikim.1.29?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) is teaching us:

> The evil desire will even bring proof from the words of our Sages: "Everyone whom people like, G-d also likes" (Aboth 3:10). But all this is false proof, for this type of reasoning is already a branch of arrogance. But the truth of the matter is, as it is written: "When a man's ways please the Lo-rd, He makes even his enemies to be at peace with him" (Prov. 16:7). And the meaning of this verse is, 'If a man does not boast before others and does not try to be liked by them because of his good deeds, and yet people like him, this is great evidence that the Holy One, Blessed be He, loves him, and has sown (the seeds of) love for him in the hearts of people and has made him a good name on their tongues. In truth there are some individuals who are loved by people and the Holy One Blessed be He hates them, for they do not fulfill His Commandments. For the Holy One Blessed be He loves only those who study the Torah and fulfill its precepts.

See also [my answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/128126/27180) where I cite R' Moshe Feinstein in his Darash Moshe Al HaTorah.

So, in a quick summary, "to find favour in G-ds eyes" can mean that the deeds you are performing, are always pleasing to G-d.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few answers but I will say two.

One is- the רטב''ה on Brachot 35 says that when the פסוק says חן it is the ultimate source of kabala from the eyes meaning when one asks for Finding favor on the eyes one is asking if I found the knowledge in the eyes of the מלאכים.

There is still one problem. There's a rule that the פסוק will also retain its simple meaning.

Thus the simple meaning of the פסוק is that one sees with their eyes. When one stands before you they would see you. If one has acted kindly, then they will see you in a positive way. if one does evil they see you in a negative way.
The phrase of saying finding favor in your eyes also tells a person to look at what I have done. I have acted properly before you and just, do not act evil towards me.

Comment: Who is the רטבה? Did you mean the ריטב״א? Where does he say this? Which passuk?

Comment: Bareisheit 18      1-5     another source is when the chachamim created brechot it says chen and that is the ritva in the gemara that uses this is the source        another area to defend the ritva is using exodus 33;13

Comment: but there is no ritva on the torah and that is why you must go to the gemara brachot

Comment: brachot 35 is where you should find that ritva

Comment: Please [edit] all relevant information into your answer itself

Comment: I am sorry for my mistake but thank you for helping me

Comment: Do you have the right daf? There doesn't appear to be the aforementioned ritva that you state?

Comment: I didn't find such a Ritba in Berachot