Parshas Noach. Why was Noah called righteous in his generation?
In the pasuk of Parshas Noach, what prompted the pasuk to write Noach was righteous in his generation? We don't find the Torah writing about any Avos or Imahos vis-a-vis they're righteous in their generation.

There’s a debate in the Gemarah regarding whether he was a Tzardik even in his generation, or considered a Tzaddik only relative to his generation.

Strongly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/128112/15256

The debate among our Rabbis how to interpret “righteous in his generation” is brought down by Rashi on the posuk

This happens to be probably the most popular question on parashat Noach. Surely this has been asked before?

No one has yet answered my question

It is significantly more important here to point out that he was a Tzadik, since the theme of the entire parshah is the wickedness and ensuing destruction of the generation with the exception of Noach.

Of note, Rashi refers to those who judge Noach favorably as רבותינו

@J.W.Tanner indeed, look what the Apter Rav says on that Rashi: יש מרבותינו דורשין אותו לשבח ויש דורשין אותו לגנאי. אצל שבח כתוב: 'יש "מרבותינו" דורשים', ואילו אחר כך כתוב: ויש שדורשים אותו לגנאי – כאן לא כתוב "רבותינו", כי אלה שדורשים לגנאי אינם רבותינו, כי רבותינו אינם דורשים לגנאי

@pine5900 as far as I can tell Y DJ has answered it? If you don't like the answer, can you explain why and edit your question with more details?

@RabbiKaii:  I heard that vort many years ago from Stephen Schwartz, but I didn't know/remember the original source, so thank you so much for providing it

The Satmar Rav (Divrei Yoel Al HaTorah, Parshas Noach, p. 117) quotes Rav Chaim Vital, and explains that being a tzadik, is not only because of one's deeds, but also the generation in which a person lives has an influence on the righteousness.
The Abarbanel teaches us that the word (תָּמִ֥ים) tamim - upright - means that Noach had no inclination to do evil. This is, because:

Noach walked with G-d, which means that he lived amongst evil people but did not follow their ways. He just followed G-d

The Gemara (Sanhedrin 108a) famously teaches us that Noach was a tzadik in his generation, but if he lived in the generation of Avraham, he would not be a tzadik per se.

With regard to the verse: “These are the generations of Noah; Noah was a righteous man, and wholehearted in his generations” (Genesis 6:9), Rabbi Yoḥanan says: Relative to the other people of his generation he was righteous and wholehearted, but not relative to those of other generations. And Reish Lakish says: In his generation he was righteous and wholehearted despite being surrounded by bad influences; all the more so would he have been considered righteous and wholehearted in other generations.

The Tevas Gome (Noach 4) says:

Noah was a righteous man, perfect in his generations; Noah walked with G-d” (Bereishis 6:9). Since he did not rebuke the people of his generation, nor did he pay attention to their actions at all, he did not mix with them. His entire manner of living was in solitude with G-d

According to some, this, e.g. Noach did not try to rebuke people, this is one of his sins (Chasam Sofer Al HaTorah, Parshas Noach).
Based on the Abarbanel, the reason why the Torah saw the need to mention that Noach was a tzadik in his generations, was to teach us that, in the generations of Noach, the people were corrupt, and most evil. Noach was upright and walked with G-d. However, as Rav Moshe Feinstein (Darash Moshe Al HaTorah, Parshas Noach) teaches: he did walk with G-d, not before G-d, as Avraham Avinu. Noach entered the ark because G-d told him to. With Avraham, all the trials and all what happened, did Avraham out of love for Hashem.

Why did you give only one of the two opinions, in the paragraph where you introduced the quote from Gemara Sanhedrin?

Because I built my answer based on that. I put in the whole piece for others to see themselves.
